# Update html dashboard cards through Vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, woocommerce

I am developing a Vue dashboard communicating with Woocommerce REST API. I have created a few dashboard cards to show total orders of the day and order count and one more card.
I have html code like below for cards:

```html
<div class="dashbord dashbord-red">
    <div class="icon-section">
        <small>Total Sales</small>
        <p> v-for="totalsales, index in totalSales">
            Total - Total is: {{ totalsales.total_sales }}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Vue js code

```js
// creating Vue instnce
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    orders: []
  },
  data: {
    totalsSales: []
  },
  mounted: function () {
    // Call the API the first time
    this.refreshData()
    // Then call the API every minute
    this.setIntervalId = setInterval(this.refreshData, 60000)
    // Updating cards  
    this.getTotalSalesToday()
  },

  methods: {
    getTotalSalesToday() {
      axios.get('https://staging.mysite.de/wp-json/wc/v3/reports/sales?date_min=2020-09-18&consumer_key=123&consumer_secret=123')
        .catch(error => {
          console.log(error);

        });
    }
  })
```

I am just getting the text inside the p tag, not the value. I could not find what am I doing wrong here?
Thank you

Comment: one typo: `<p> v-for="totalsales, index in totalSales">` should be `<p v-for="totalsales, index in totalSales">`

Answer (score 1):

I see a few potential issues that could be the cause of the problem:

1. As Sphinx [notes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63961118/update-html-dashboard-cards-through-vue-js#comment113104201_63961118), there's a typo in the `<p>` tag.
2. You have `totalsSales` in `data` but `totalSales` in the `v-for`.
3. You declare `data` twice.
4. If you are using components: "When defining a component, data must be declared as a function that returns the initial data object" ([docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#data))
5. It isn't clear from the code you posted how `totalSales` is supposed to be populated. Is `refreshData` doing it? Unless you have an interceptor set up that you didn't post, `getTotalSalesToday` isn't updating `totalSales`. You'd need a `.then` that uses the response from the server to set `totalSales`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yeah got it the mistakes. Also refreshData() method is fetching order details for html table for that I am using 'data : orders[ ]'